# Java heap space with MongoDB

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, mongodb

I use Tomcat, Eclipse, Java EE, MongoDB.

when I run my java program which is to connect to a mongoDB database and save some data, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-19"
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.<init>(HeapCharBuffer.java:57)
        at java.nio.CharBuffer.allocate(CharBuffer.java:331)
        at com.mongodb.ByteEncoder.<init>(ByteEncoder.java:546)
        at com.mongodb.ByteEncoder.<init>(ByteEncoder.java:48)
        at com.mongodb.ByteEncoder$1.createNew(ByteEncoder.java:79)
        at com.mongodb.ByteEncoder$1.createNew(ByteEncoder.java:76)
        at com.mongodb.util.SimplePool._get(SimplePool.java:140)
        at com.mongodb.util.SimplePool.get(SimplePool.java:106)
        at com.mongodb.util.SimplePool.get(SimplePool.java:95)
        at com.mongodb.ByteEncoder.get(ByteEncoder.java:66)
        at com.mongodb.DBMessage.<init>(DBMessage.java:52)
        at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:166)
        at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:132)
        at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:127)
        at web.ApplicationInterface.doGet(ApplicationInterface.java:125)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110),
```

`EDIT`

I have already changed the memory allowed by Eclipse, but I still have the same problem.

This is the code that causes the problem.

```
db.requestStart();
try 
{
    coll.insert(doc);
    DBObject err = db.getLastError();
} 
finally 
{
    db.requestDone();
}
```

`PROBLEM SOLVED`

The version of MongoDB was old and full of bug, I am now using version 2.8, and Now it's working, Thank you

Comment: Which versions of Tomcat, Java, MongoDB are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java 6, mongodb 2.0.6 & Apache TomEE 1.0.0

Comment: 'allowed by Eclipse' means? Did you add memory settings in run configurations > Arguments

Comment: what is `doc` ? add the first line in `try`, System.out.println(doc);

Comment: @Tito George : I mean allocated (not allowed)

Comment: I got that, My question is where did you change the memory settings? just i am trying to understand.

Comment: @TitoGeorge I changed it in the Eclipse.ini file

Answer (score 3):

try to increase heap size

```
JVM -- keys
 -Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
 -Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to allow more memory for your JVM, with `-Xmx1024m` option (for example): [How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error (64MB heap size)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335)

Answer (score 0):

How much data are you trying to save?
I think you are trying to store large amount of data in one shot to MongoDB.

Comment: There not a lot of data to save, just 10 rows

Answer (score 0):

Edit these in Run Configurations
For Run Configurations 
Right click your project root --> Run As--> Run Configurations

[image: Add -Xms<size> and -Xmx<size> in VM arguments]